# dynamically hide/show and resize columns of grid

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, gridview

I am trying to create a footer in my application where I need to hide or show tabs based on booleans - if the functionality is enable it will show the tab, no otherwise.

In the main page I have something like this:

```
<items:ItemsPageBase.ItemsPageBaseFooterLayout>

    <local:NavigationGrid />

</items:ItemsPageBase.ItemsPageBaseFooterLayout>
```

NavigationGrid looks like that:

```
<Grid
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
x:Class="App.Mobile.UI.Views.Issue.IssueNavigationGrid"

BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource NavigationBarColor}"
ColumnSpacing="0"
HeightRequest="70"
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
Padding="0"
RowSpacing="0"
VerticalOptions="End">

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> 
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<controls:IconButton
    Command="{Binding Tab1}"
    CornerRadius="20"
    HeightRequest="40"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    WidthRequest="60"/>

<controls:IconButton
    Grid.Column="2"
    Command="{Binding Tab2}"
    CornerRadius="20"
    HeightRequest="40"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    WidthRequest="60"/>

...Tab3, Tab4

<controls:IconButton
    Grid.Column="5"
    Command="{Binding Tab5}"
    CornerRadius="20"
    HeightRequest="40"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    WidthRequest="60"/>
```

[image]

How do I dynamically change the column definition based on a value?
For instance, there is the case where Tab3 is disabled so I want to fit only 4 tabs on the footer and the content needs to be correctly formatted.

So far my only option would have been to create different grid for each combinantion which makes 0 sense and it would need one to many template.

Thanks

Comment: Use "auto" instead of " * " in the column definitions that way the columns width will be zero if the contents visibility is set to false. That means there is no empty space and the other tabs should be next to each other

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding Grid Column Width on Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65759775/binding-grid-column-width-on-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

thanks! At the end I have solved by adding an empty grid with a NAME in the xaml:

```
<Grid
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
x:Class="App.Mobile.UI.Views.Issue.IssueNavigationGrid"
x:Name = "IssueGrid"
BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource NavigationBarColor}"
ColumnSpacing="0"
HeightRequest="70"
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
Padding="0"
RowSpacing="0"
VerticalOptions="End">

</Grid>
```

And then I have created dynamically the columns in C# based on my needs as:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class IssueNavigationGrid
{
    private readonly IApplicationSettingDataService service;
    public bool IssueHasKits { get; private set; }

    public IssueNavigationGrid()
    {
        _service = applicationSettingsDataService;
        InitializeComponent();

        IssueGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        IssueGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        IssueGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

        var columnNumber = 1;

        var showBatchItemsOnly = new IconLabelButton
        {
            LabelIcon = "\uf00c",
            Label = LocalizationHandler.Instance["SELECTED"],
        };

        var showAllItems = new IconLabelButton
        {
            LabelIcon = "\uf0ca",
            Label = LocalizationHandler.Instance["ITEMS"],
        };

        var showKits = new IconLabelButton
        {
            LabelIcon = "\uf466",
            Label = LocalizationHandler.Instance["KITS"],
        };

        IssueHasKits = service.GetApplicationSetting<bool>("IssueHasKits");

        IssueGrid.Children.Add(showBatchItemsOnly, 0, 0);

        IssueGrid.Children.Add(showAllItems, 1, 0);

        if (IssueHasKits)
        {
            columnNumber++;
            IssueGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            IssueGrid.Children.Add(showKits, columnNumber, 0);
        }
    }
 }
```

That works for me - thanks

In the above examples the only one tab the I want to show/hide is "KITS"